# appcfg.sh update throwing a 401 error all of a sudden

Tags: google-app-engine

Two days ago everything was fine. Today, I get a 401 error when trying to update a version on one staging instance. It still works fine on our other staging instance and on our prod instance.

We are on the latest appengine sdk. Anyone know why we are getting the following error on only one instance?

WARNING: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/deploy?module=default&app_id=xxxxxxxxxxx2&version=213&
401 Unauthorized
Your version of the App Engine SDK is out-of-date. Please update your SDK at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/download#appengine_sdk and your Maven plugin, if necessary, according to the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/maven
This is try #0
95% Rolling back the update.

Comment: I don't think this question is off-topic. Reproduction may be hard, but the same issue does happen for some users (including me), and the answer below does resolve the issue (for me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I came across the answer. The ~/.appcfg_oauth2_token_java had the wrong credentials. I deleted that and tried again. It took me through the OAUTH flow and then it worked.

Comment: I had the same issue with AppEngine Python, and the issue was resolved following this answer. But the file was named ~/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens instead of ~/.appcfg_oauth2_token_java, maybe because I'm using Python instead.